# My Css is not working on material ui components in react app

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

In react app , I am using Material UI framework for css. I have used my own style on some components Material Ui. I found that My customized style is disappeared and not applying on components automatically.[image: This is a Login Page where I applied css but not working.]

Components part :

```
<Box className={css.form}>


                        <TextField className={css.text} label="Enter your Username" />
                        <TextField className={css.text} label="Enter your Password" />

                        <Button className={css.loginBtn} variant='contained'>Login</Button>
                        <Typography style={{ textAlign: 'center', margin: '20px 10px 0 0', color: '#484747e8', fontSize: '15px' }}>OR</Typography>
                        <Button onClick={ ()=> toggleSignup()} className={css.signinBtn}>Create an account</Button>

                    </Box>
```

css for component

```
.form{ 
    padding: 24px 25px;
    display: flex ;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.text{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.668);
    color: #383636;
}

.loginBtn{
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-transform: none;
    background: #484747e8;
}
.loginBtn:hover{
    background-color:#383636;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.signinBtn{
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-transform: none;
    color: rgb(2, 2, 48);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 1px  #e1dcdc;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.signinBtn:hover{
    /*  */
    /* color: whitesmoke; */
    color: black;
    background-color: #383636;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

style is not appeared.

Comment: i am not sure how you are exporting and importing - maybe this is new lol but it looks like regular ol css from what you provided...and it seems you are assigning an object notation not a class name (string) to `className`  - try `className="loginBtn"`?